# Why does modular exponentiation go wrong when we change datatype of variable "u" from long long to int?

Tags: c++, integer, long-integer, modular-arithmetic

When datatype of variable "u" is long long the modular exponentiation works well but when it is changed to int it gives wrong answers.

For example when (2,447,1e9+7) are passed as arguments "long long u" gives 941778035 as the answer but "int u" gives 0 as the answer. The functions are as follows :-

```
int modpow(int x, int n, int m) {  //to calculate x^n%m
    if (n == 0) return 1%m;
    long long u = modpow(x,n/2,m);
    u = (u*u)%m;
    if (n%2 == 1) u = (u*x)%m;
    return u;
}
```

```
int modpow(int x, int n, int m) {  //to calculate x^n%m
    if (n == 0) return 1%m;
    int u = modpow(x,n/2,m);
    u = (u*u)%m;
    if (n%2 == 1) u = (u*x)%m;
    return u;
}
```

```
int main(){    //used as main in program with x = 2 and m = 1e9+7 and n is given by user
   int n, m = 1e9+7;
   cin>>n;
   int pow = modpow(2,n,m);
   cout<<pow;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: On your compiler, how big is int and longlong? Are they both 63 bit? Does every possible value of `(u*x)` and `(u*u)` fit in the data type? Does `(u*x)%m` always bring it back to a new value that will fit next time round?

Comment: earlier my main function was wrong now i have updated it sorry for inconvenience...

Comment: `1000000006 * 1000000006` has 60 binary digits.

Comment: If you add this `assert(u <= static_cast<decltype(u)>(std::sqrt(std::numeric_limits<decltype(u)>::max())));` before doing the `u = (u*u)%m;` you can ensure that the calculation isn't going to exceed the capacity of the variable.

Comment: @molbdnilo but we never multiplied the power i.e. n = 1e9+7 like that we are multiplying u and x

Comment: @VIr `u` may be as large as 1e9+6, since that's the largest possible result of the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Think about `modpow(1e9, 2, 1e9+7)`

```
if (2 == 0) // no
int u = modpow(1e9, 1, 1e9+7);

  if (1 == 0) // no
  int u = modpow(1e9, 0, 1e9+7);

    if (0 == 0) return 1;

  int u = 1;
  u = 1; // (1*1) % (1e9+7)
  if (1 % 2 == 1) u = 1e9; // (1 * 1e9) % (1e9+7)

int u = 1e9;
u = (1e9 * 1e9)%(1e9+7); // OUCH!
```

1e9 * 1e9 overflows if `int u` is only 32 bit wide, which *is* the case on most of modern computer environments (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models )